# How to prove that $\sup A, A \subseteq \mathbb R$ is always an adherent point

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was trying to prove the following proposition:

> Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ closed and open. Show that $A = \emptyset$ or $A = \mathbb R$.

I think the basic outline of the proof should be correct, however there were some things I am not sure about:

> Suppose $A \neq \emptyset$ and $A \neq \mathbb R$.
>   Without loss of generality, we can assume that A is bounded from the top by some constant $M$.
>   Since $A \neq \emptyset$ it follows from the completeness axiom that there is $s := \sup A$.
>   Because A is closed $s$ must be in $A$, otherwise if there was $\varepsilon > 0$ with $U_{\varepsilon}(s) \cap A = \emptyset$, $s$ would not be the supremum since $s - \varepsilon < s$.

This is something I am not sure of. Can you just say that or do you have to prove that if $A$ is closed then $\sup A \in A$?  Does my proof suffice? I was thinking about saying that since $A$ is closed, every adherent point is in $A$, but do I know that $\sup A$ is an adherent point? Continuing:

> Since A is open, there is $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $U_{\varepsilon}(s) \subseteq A$. This is a contradiction because $s < s + \varepsilon$ and thereby is not a maximum/supremum. This shows that it must be $A = \mathbb R$ or $A = \emptyset$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Why do you assume $A$ to be bounded?

Comment: The case that $A$ is bounded from below follows from an analogous argument. The case where A is unbounded can be handled with $B = \mathbb R \backslash A$ right?

Comment: An unbounded set does not necessarily have an unbounded complement. For instance, $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{N}$ are both unbounded.

Comment: Ah, you are right. So my proof is completely wrong?

Comment: It is a union of open intervals whose complement is also a union of open intervals.

Comment: You are right to consider the idea of a boundary, but not a bound. Your A is a UNION of open intervals, not (necessarily) an open interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex Provost's comment shows, your proof is not quite correct; it starts on a wrong assumption. The hint below points in another direction to answering the problem.

**Hint:** If $A \neq \emptyset$ and $A \neq \mathbb{R}$, then $B=\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ is also open (and also closed) and nonempty. This implies $A\sqcup B$ is a disjoint union of nonempty, real open sets that equals $\mathbb{R}$. Why is this a problem?

---

EDIT: Let $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, and suppose without loss of generality that $a<b$. Consider the set

$$S=\{x \in [a,b]\,|\, x \in A\}$$

We have that $S \neq \emptyset$ because $a\in A$, so we may talk about $\sup S \leq b < \infty$. Since $A$ and $B$ decompose $\mathbb{R}$, it must be that $\sup S$ belongs to exactly one of them. Which one? Find a contradiction here.

EDIT EDIT: We will show $s \notin A$.

Indeed, suppose $s \in A$. Since $b \in B$ and $s \leq b$, we must have $a\leq s <b$. Now, since $A$ is open, there must be an open ball centered on $s$ and contained in $A$. In particular, $(s,b) \cap A \neq \emptyset$. But this contradicts $s$ being $\sup S$ (because there is some $x >s$ in $S$), so it must be $s \notin A$.

Now, we show that $s \notin B$.

Indeed, suppose $s \in B$. Since $B$ is open, there is an open ball centered on $b$ and contained in $B$. In particular, there is some $\epsilon>0$ with $(b-\epsilon,b]\subset B$. If $s=b$, this would imply $\sup S \leq b-\epsilon$, a contradiction. It follows that $s<b$.

Now, notice that $(s,b)\subset B$. Indeed, if some $x$ in $(s,b)$ were in $A$, there would be a contradiction with $s$ being $\sup S$ (because there would be some $x >s$ in $S$). Moreover, because $B$ is open, there is an open ball centered on $s$ and contained in $B$. In particular, there is some $\epsilon>0$ with $(s-\epsilon,s]\subset B$. But this implies $(s-\epsilon,s]\cup(s,b)=(s-\epsilon,b]\subset B$, so $s=\sup S \leq s-\epsilon$. This is a clear contradiction, so we must have $s \notin B$.

Comment: I just realized that I have to handle the case where $A$ is neither bounded from the top nor from below. I am then looking at $B = \mathbb R \backslash A$. This looks like a problem since it doesn't seem to be possible (if you're talking about connectedness of $\mathbb R$, I am not allowed to use that).

Comment: Well, even if you're not allowed to use the result per se, the argument you use for it will be of a 'connectedness' quality. Regardless, you can do it with elementary analysis arguments. See the edit.

Comment: So I guess I have to proof that it is not possible to partition $\mathbb R$ into two disjoint, non-empty real open sets, i.e. that it is connected? Do I have to use the completeness axiom for that (that was a hint on my exercise sheet).

Comment: You don't have to prove *exactly* that, but the techniques used in the proof most definitely will be the ones also solve this question.

Comment: So I said, in case $s = b$ it follows that $s \in B$. But also $b \in S$, yielding $s \in S \implies s \in A$. Contradiction. But how do I argue when $s < b$?

Comment: See the second edit.

Comment: Thanks! That was quite more than I thought :)

Comment: You're welcome! There are simpler ways, but this uses very elementary means.

Answer (score 0):

A's boundary points are precisely the boundary points of its complement. But then if A has boundary points either A or its complement contains its own boundary point. But then some open interval contains this, and this must be its boundary point. This is impossible so neither A nor its complement have any boundary points.